# How can I convert an array of objects into JSON (and return it)?

Tags: javascript, json, local-storage

For simplicity's sake, I have a JavaScript Array of `car` objects as below (one example):

```
var car = {
    "color": "red",
    "fuelType": "diesel"
}
```

I'd like to store this array of objects in the user's localStorage and be able to retrieve and add/delete to it.

Here is some example code that I cannot seem to get right.

```
addCar(car);

function getCars() {
    var cars = [];
    if (localStorage['cars']) {
        cars = localStorage['cars'];
    }

    return cars;
}

function addCar(car) {
    var cars = getCars();
    cars.push(car);
    localStorage['cars'] = cars;
}
```

**How can I convert an array of objects into JSON (and return it)?** `localStorage` only allows for the storage of Strings. I need to convert the array of objects into a JSON format, but I am not sure how.

Comment: So... what is your question?

Comment: I guess I'll repeat it here: How can I convert an array of objects into JSON (and return it)?

Comment: Okay, so you provided code that should do that. What's wrong with it?

Comment: `localStorage` only allows for the storage of Strings. I need to convert the array of objects into a JSON format, but I am not sure how.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, local storage only supports strings, so you have to use `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()` to get data in and out.

Comment: I understand that. I'm not able to convert the array into a JSON string though

Comment: Should work with just an array, but maybe put it inside an object `var carsObj = { cars: getCars() }` and then stringify that.

Comment: @Redandwhite Did you even read his answer? He tells you to use `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()`... `JSON.stringify(cars)` will return a string representation of your array. What aren't you understanding here?